# Calculate : $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{asin\theta} r^2 drd\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I need help with the following integral :

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{asin\theta} r^2 drd\theta$$

What I did :

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{asin\theta} r^2 drd\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{asin\theta} r^3 drd\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(asin\theta)^3 d\theta$$

What is the integral of $(asin\theta)^3$?
Any Ideas?

Thanks in advence!

Comment: You mean $\frac13r^3 |_0^{a\sin{\theta}}$ not $\frac13\int_0^{a\sin\theta}r^3dr$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last integral should be $\mathrm{d} \theta$ I believe. Also, since you're integrating an odd function over a symmetric interval, the result should be zero.

Comment: You'r right about the last integral, typo.

Comment: All clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake in your process. It should be:

> $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{asin\theta} r^2 drd\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{3}(asin\theta)^3 d\theta=0$$

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment than an answer, especially since you don't show how to get the final zero and the reason it is zero has already been posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a$ is a constant, $\sin^3(\theta)$ can be broken down into $\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. $\sin^2(\theta)$ can be simplified using the identity $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$. Then use integration by parts to solve it.

Comment: It is $\sin^{-1}$ function actually I think.

Comment: I edited this post so that you can start the process on understanding how to format equations. So please take a look at [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as this will greatly improve your interaction on this site.